# Utterly confused why; AttributeError: 'Root' object has no attribute 'entry1'

Tags: python, tkinter

This is probably a really simple mistake that I have made, but for the life of me I cannot figure out what it is. I would appreciate a fresh perspective on this as I have been blankly staring at this, and adding numerous print debug statements to attempt to figure out what has been causing this. Every single other function I have written using a similar structure in this class has worked without an issue. Please help.

Relevant add_entry() function on line 61+

Error message and traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:/Users/morga/OneDrive/Documents/Programming/Python/Projects/Tkinter/Manager.py", line 83, in <module>
  main_window.add_entry(insert="enter text here", show="*")
File "c:/Users/morga/OneDrive/Documents/Programming/Python/Projects/Tkinter/Manager.py", line 73, in add_entry
  exec("self.entry"+ str(self.entry_count) + ".insert(" + str(self.insert_index) + ", '" +   self.insert + "')")
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Root' object has no attribute 'entry1'
```

Code

```
# Comment style: code snippets; 'variable' or 'code snippet', "string", function, Class; begin each comment with a capitalised word 

# Stuff to implement: other widgets in root class, actual GUI for program (ideas: resturant manager, GUI creator)


# Import tkinter as the alias tk, import mainloop from tkinter
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import mainloop






# Any function referenced in a button must be above this 


class Root(): # Define Root class for GUI windows
    """
    Root is the main window class for the GUI which returns an instance with a Tk window, which    can then be used to run class functions to return a widget on the window.

    Functions:
    add_button(text,command): returns button added to window
    add_label(text): returns label added to indow

    Notes:
    remember to run {instance}.window.mainloop() at the end of the program 

    """

    def __init__(self): # Initialise the class
        self.window = tk.Tk()  # Assign the window to 'self.window', assign 'widget_count' to 0, assign 'window_name' to "self.window"
        self.label_count = 0
        self.button_count = 0
        self.entry_count = 0
        self.window_name = "self.window"


    def add_button(self,text,command=None): # Function to add a button onto the window of the Root class instance

        self.command = command # Assign the parameter command to 'self.command', the parameter text to 'self.text', and assign 'BUTTON' to a string formatted to pass through parameters and create a button with them
        self.text = text
        self.button_count += 1

        try: # Catch error thrown by 'self.command.__name__' if no function is passed as parameter and remove 'command=' from BUTTON string instead
            name = self.command.__name__
            self.BUTTON = str("self.button" + str(self.button_count) + " = tk.Button(" +     str(self.window_name) + ",text='" + str(self.text) + "',command=" + str(name) + ").pack()")
        except AttributeError:
            self.BUTTON = str("self.button" + str(self.button_count) + " = tk.Button(" +     str(self.window_name) + ",text='" + str(self.text) + "').pack()")

        exec(self.BUTTON)  # Execute add button string as if it was python code

    def add_label(self,text):

        self.text = text # Assign the parameter text to 'self.text', and assign 'LABEL' to a string formatted to pass through parameters and create a label with them
        self.LABEL = str("self.label" + str(self.label_count) + " = tk.Label(" + str(self.window_name) + ",text='" + str(self.text) +  "').pack()")
        self.label_count += 1

        exec(self.LABEL) # Execute add label string as if it was python code

    def add_entry(self,insert=None,insert_index=0,show=None):

        self.show = show # Assign the parameter show to 'self.self', the parameter insert to 'self.insert', the parameter insert_index to 'self.insert_index', and assign 'ENTRY' to a string formatted to pass through parameters and create a entry with them
        self.insert = insert
        self.insert_index = insert_index
        self.entry_count += 1

        if self.show != None:
            self.ENTRY = str("self.entry" + str(self.entry_count) + " = tk.Entry(" +     str(self.window_name) + ",show='" + str(self.show) +  "').pack()")
        else:
            self.ENTRY = str("self.entry" + str(self.entry_count) + " = tk.Entry(" + str(self.window_name) + ").pack()")
        if self.insert != None:
            exec("self.entry"+ str(self.entry_count) + ".insert(" + str(self.insert_index) + ", '" + self.insert + "')")

        exec(self.LABEL) # Execute add entry string as if it was python code

# Other widgets yet to be implemented


main_window = Root() # Create an instance of Root class and assign main_window to it
main_window.add_button("this works") # Add a button with text of "this works"
main_window.add_label("ok") # Add a label with text of "ok"
main_window.add_entry(insert="enter text here", show="*")


main_window.window.mainloop() # Start the mainloop of the GUI to show the window
```

Comment: your `exec` statement is trying to `.insert` on a attribute named `self.entry1`. You haven't created self.entry1, so you can't `insert` on it.

Comment: Using `exec` is generally considered an anti-pattern. You should probably use a list stored in a single attribute, rather than trying to create attributes with numbers in their names. If you need the API of those attributes, either create them using `setattr` or consider faking them using `__getattr__` and a list.

Comment: @user1558604, I can see that it isn't defined, but I cannot find out why. I have checked the value of ENTRY and it should have defined self.entry1 exactly like very other string exec in the program

Comment: @Blckkknght I can see why using exec() might be bad onsidering the circumstance, but any info on how I can rewrite this? perhaps you could rewrite a section of the function to demonstrate this because I have never crossed this aspect of python before

Comment: What about using a list. rather than have a variable for every entry, have one entries list, and use subscripts for the numbers. This has other benefits, like being able to iterate over the lists, and finding the length easily.

Comment: As a good rule of thumb you should never use `exec` in this manner. Why aren't you storing widget references in a list or dictionary instead?

Comment: John: Rewriting your code to not use `exec()` is a completely different question — so I doubt you'll get much help on it here…

Comment: @martineau I can completely see the point of commenting this.... But yes, I had realised that and I've already thought of how to do it so not really needed.

Comment: John: ...and doing so would likely make this question moot.

Comment: You have not executed `exec(self.ENTRY)` to create the entry.

Comment: @acw1668 I see the error now, I did actually execute that, but only after I attempted to exec the insert string. Regardless, I have found a more pythonic, and frankly, easier way to do this with lists so altough its helpful to know where I went wrong it is not relevant.